# How to set a random time in a datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

My instructions are as follows:
Read the date columns in as timestamps, convert them to YYYY/MM/DD
hours:minutes:seconds format, where you set hours minutes and seconds to random
values appropriate to their range

Here is column of the data frame we are suppose to alter to datetime:

```
Order date
11/12/2016
11/24/2016
6/12/2016
10/12/2016
...
```

And here is the date time I need

```
2016/11/12 (random) hours:minutes:seconds
2016/11/24 (random) hours:minutes:seconds
...
```

My main question is how do I get random hours minutes and seconds. The rest I can figure out with the documentation

Comment: Please provide your dataframe as clean text, not image

Comment: parse to datetime and add a random number of seconds (0, ...86399) as a timedelta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate random numbers between 0 and 86399 (number of seconds in a day - 1) and convert to a TimeDelta with [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
import numpy as np
time = pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(0, 60*60*24-1, size=len(df)), unit='s')

df['Order date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order date']).add(time)
```

Output:

```
           Order date
0 2016-11-12 02:21:53
1 2016-11-24 13:26:00
2 2016-06-12 15:13:03
3 2016-10-12 14:45:12
```

Comment: that could add a whole day, no?

Comment: @FObersteiner OK 86399 then ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the data in `'%Y-%m-%d'` format but the data is in `"%d/%m/%Y"` format. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior to find out how to convert the date to your desired format.

Comment: ok, thank you, do you know how I would randomize the hours minutes and seconds?

Comment: DandyApe, show us what you tried. What code? What documentation pages did you search?